# Como listar NULL em um LEFT JOIN mesmo ele retornando junções?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A situação encontrada foi que:

Estou efetuando uma junção entre representantes e vendedores, e em outra situação essa junção é feita com outra de vendas. 
Há vendas sem vendedores porém são relacionadas ao representante, e desejo captar e verificar a falha desse relacionamento nessas vendas.

Problema:

Estou efetuando um `LEFT JOIN` e até certo ponto ele me atende conforme a própria limitação da cláusula. Só que eu preciso que quando eu fizer um relacionamento entre o representante e os vendedores, mesmo que ele encontre algum deles, também me retorne um `NULL`.

Exemplo atual:

```
SELECT r.cod as cod_representante, v.cod_vendedor 
FROM representantes r 
LEFT JOIN vendedores v 
ON v.cod_representante = r.cod
```

Isso me retorna algo como :

```
cod_representante | cod_vendedor
1                 | 1
1                 | 2
2                 | NULL
3                 | NULL
4                 | 3
```

O resultado desejado seria algo como:

```
cod_representante | cod_vendedor
1                 | 1
1                 | 2
1                 | NULL
2                 | NULL
3                 | NULL
4                 | 3
4                 | NULL
```

Comment: você quer, para cada cod_representante tenha um correspondente NULL em cod_vendedor, mesmo que cod_vendedor tenha um valor correspondente?

Comment: Exato, @GOKUSSJGod. Mesmo que tenha valores na junção, quero incrementar um valor a mais, sendo NULL.

Comment: Bem estranho sua necessidade, mas acredito que você tenha que fazer mais uma união de suas tabelas, talvez sendo em um subselect.                  Poderia posta suas tabelas ?

Comment: Sim, é estranho porém foi a solução temporária que vi e que de forma imediata atende esse problema que descrevi.

Comment: Deu certo da forma que postei?

Comment: Deu sim, efetuando algumas adaptações porém serviu-me bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se é isso.

```
declare @representantes table
(
   cod int
)


declare @vendedores table
(
cod_vendedor int,
cod_representante int
)

insert into @representantes values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)

insert into @vendedores values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,4)


select * from
(
    SELECT r.cod as cod_representante, v.cod_vendedor 
    FROM @representantes r 
    JOIN @vendedores v 
    ON v.cod_representante = r.cod
    union all
    select * from
    (
        select r1.cod as cod_representante, v1.cod_vendedor 
        from  @vendedores v1
        full outer join @representantes r1
        on v1.cod_vendedor is null
    )d
    where d.cod_representante is not null
) d
order by cod_representante, CASE WHEN cod_vendedor IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Use o INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
   r.cod as cod_representante, 
   v.cod_vendedor 
FROM 
   representantes r 
INNER JOIN vendedores v ON v.cod_representante = r.cod
```

Comment: Desse modo é que não vem os nulos mesmo.

Comment: Assim nem os representantes sem vendedores serão listados, Raphael. O que preciso é que "incremente" um NULL mesmo listando vendedores.